# Renewing an expired German blue card

Tags: germany, blue-card

I already worked in Germany for more than 3 years as a skilled worker and a blue card holder(2018 -> 2021), then I left Germany, moved outside EU/Uk, I'm wandering if I return to Germany next year(2022), with a gap of more than one year, how this will affect my situation in Germany, I may certainly need to apply for a new blue card, but my concern is, the pension program, since I payed for 3 years now, will it get accumulated to the next years? In terms of after 2 years I reach 5 years of pension participation and eligible to receive a German state pension.

The other concern is when I apply for a permanent residency, will I get my previous 3 years considered in the calculation of the 33 months for a blue card holder to get a permanent residence? Or everything will start from scratch as I never worked and payed tax in Germany.

Comment: Your monthly contributions to the pension system **do not** expire. [Section 18cPermanent settlement permit for skilled workers](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0406) make no mention of time interuptions (as apposed to nationalisation which does).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for the promptly reply, it's relieving to hear that, that's what I also noticed when I read the link you provided above.

Comment: As a follow up question, I'm also wandering when I get registered for the second time in the social security insurance, if they I'll create a new insurance number for me or I can use my first one optioned in 2018.

Comment: If you supply your new employer with your present insurance number, there will be no need be no need for them to apply for a new one. You should also apply for a **Versicherungsverlauf** ([Deutsche Rentenversicherung - FAQs - Versicherungsverlauf](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/DRV/DE/Rente/Allgemeine-Informationen/Wissenswertes-zur-Rente/FAQs/Versicherung/Versicherungsverlauf_Liste.html)) when leaving Germany, which contains all relevant information. Check the result to insure that it is complete.

Comment: Really appreciate all your responses , I sent emails to different German institutions including Deutsche Rentenversicherung but none of them respond until now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Amazing, just by using my blue card + NFC card reader + AusweisApp2 , I'm able to logging to Deutsche Rentenversicherung , and request all the services including the pension history !! Even I'm in UK the service didn't denied the access ! Good.